# How To Define API Blueprint X-Auth-Token Header

Tags: api, rest, apiblueprint

I have a number of services that require an X-Auth-Token header to be sent similar to the below:

```
X-Auth-Token: 2e5db4a3-c80f-4cfe-ad35-7e781928f7a2
```

I would like to be able to specify this in my API documentation following the API Blueprint standard. However, from what I can tell from the  [API Blueprint headers section definition](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-headers-section), you can only specify literal values (e.g. `Accept-Charset: utf-8`) and not a schema for what the header should look like (e.g. something like `X-Auth-Token (string)`).

I get the impression that Traits might help with this problem but it's a little over my head at the moment. Can anyone tell me how to specify that all requests to a given action (or set of actions) require an X-Auth-Token header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about not being able to define a schema for headers. Unfortunately, API Blueprint doesn't support it yet.

Until something like that is supported, you can use the literal value for the header like the following:

```
+ Headers

    X-Auth-Token: 2e5db4a3-c80f-4cfe-ad35-7e781928f7a2
```

API Blueprint also does not support any `Traits` currently. I am afraid you might have been confused by reading other feature requests.